# Find cluster of points within a 14K dataset which are laying within a circle of a certain radius

Tags: spatial-cluster

- I have a dataset of geolocated points, which are dispersed over a large area
- I need to find clusters of a minimum number of X points within these sets which are laying within a circle of which the radius is R
- I want to find those clusters, retreive the orginal data of the point in the cluster but also the geographical midpoint of the point within that cluster

Comment: Which GIS software are you asking about? What have you tried and why didnt it work?

Comment: sounds like Openshaw's Optimum Bombing strategy - https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0260982782900143